# setInterval( ) -- unexpected identifier - but it works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` if it works once?

There are a bunch of these on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unexpected%20identifier).  The punchline is usually a typo somewhere in the script.

It works once, then it gives 1 error message a second.

Here I am changing the colors of states on a map:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
colors = [ 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)','rgba(0,255,0,0.1)','rgba(0,0,255,0.1)'  ];

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(
        $("ul").children().eq( Math.floor(50*Math.random())).css('color', colors[Math.floor(3*Math.random())] )
    ,1000);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are missing `function(){}` to wrap your code.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("ul").children().eq( Math.floor(50*Math.random())).css('color', colors[Math.floor(3*Math.random())] )
},1000);
```

it works once because it executes your inner-code looking for a function or string to be returned. When one isn't, it fails with a js error.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval accept parametres in quotes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
colors = [ 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)','rgba(0,255,0,0.1)','rgba(0,0,255,0.1)'  ];

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(
        '$("ul").children().eq( Math.floor(50*Math.random())).css("color", colors[Math.floor(3*Math.random())] )'
    ,1000);

});
</script>
```